# Session Flag Doesn't Direct to Login Page

Tags: php, session

I have a home page that before entering the page the user must login first. I have put session start in the head of the page, but when I enter the url of the page, it doesn;t direct me to the login page in fact I have not login yet.

**This is my session start (index.php):**

```
<?php
@session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if(  $_SESSION['flag']==1)
    echo'<script>window.location="login.php";</script>';
?>
```

**This is the login-config.php:**

```
<?php 
ob_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$con =mysqli_connect(".com","sih","st1","ceuser");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$myemail= $_POST['myemail'];
$mypassword= $_POST['mypassword'];

$sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail='".$myemail."' and  mypassword='".$mypassword."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
    header("location:index.php");
    exit; 
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I guess I am missing something. I am very new in Php and I want to learn it. Please help me.

Comment: (Tip) It's advised to not suppress errors with `@`. You're missing a lot of stuff here. What is `$count`? How does `login-config.php` come into it? When/where is `$_SESSION['user']` set?

Comment: What do you mean by not suppress errors with @? It's difficult to me. Btw, I update my code, but pleas don't focus to mySql or mysqli (depreciate).

Comment: `@` suppresses (doesn't show) errors that may occur from executing `session_start()`. Just a heads up - you're mixing `mysqli` and `mysql`

Comment: I know that mixing. But for this time I think the problem is not coming from there. The problem is the index.php page should direct the user to login page if they have not login at all.

Comment: The index `flag` is never created (in the code you've given) in `$_SESSION`. This may be an issue.

Comment: Please tell me how to correctly create that. Php is not easy to me....

Comment: If you mean that I have to set the $_SESSION['flag']=0; after the $count, I have tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would redo your logic so that;

- No sessions indexes are created without the user logging in

For your index, use;

```
<?php

session_start();

if( array_key_exists('logged_in', $_SESSION) ) {
   //They've logged in
   //Redirect to whatever page
   //You may want to check that $_SESSION['username'] holds a valid username
   header('Location: loggedin.php');
   die;
} else {
   //They've not logged in
   //Redirect to login page
   header('Location: login.php');
   die;
}
```

Now that we have a basic "router", we can modify your `login-config.php` file.

```
// ...
if( $count == 1 ) {
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
   header("location:loggedin.php");
   exit; 
}
```

Now, `loggedin.php`

```
<?php

session_start();

if( array_key_exists('logged_in', $_SESSION) ) {
   //Check $_SESSION['username'] holds a valid username in your database.
   if( $blUsernameIsValid ) {
       // Continue
       echo "Hello ". $_SESSION['username'] ."! You have logged in";
   } else {
      session_destroy();
      unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
      header('Location: index.php');
      die;
   }
} else {
   //Unauthorised access
   http_response_code(401);
   echo "Unauthorised. Please <a href=\"login.php\">Login</a>";
   die;
}
```

### Useful resources

- [How to Create a Secure Login Script in PHP and MySQL](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)
- [PHP-Login Project](http://www.php-login.net/)
- [A Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB553GB553&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20create%20login%20script)
- [Stackoverflow Questions](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB553GB553&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php+login+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now I am confused with the loggedin.php. I don't have this file in the question.

Comment: @AlKush It's purely there for illustration, to show you the flow. You can replace it with whatever you have. (Either the whole file, or the part in `index.php` where it redirects the user)